# Limit selection of check box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Limit selection of check box

My code looks like...

```
foreach($res as $res)
    echo '<div class="ediv"><input type="checkbox" class="echeck" name="pr[]" value="'.trim($res['product']).'"/>'.trim($res['product']).'</div>';
```

dynamically created code looks like this in browser...

```
<div class="ediv">
        <input type="checkbox" value="Water" name="pr[]" class="echeck">Water
</div>
```

How to set limit of selection of dynamically created checkboxes...??

i tried too many logics.. but all are not working.. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Limit selection to what?

Comment: limit number of selected checkbox

Answer (score 1):

```
var limit = 4;

$("input[name='pr[]']").change(function(e){

   if($("input[name='pr[]']:checked").length>limit)
       this.checked=false;

});
```

Its a simple logic, just check if the length of selected elemets array is greater then limit then don't check it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var limit = 3;
$('input.echeck').on('change', function(evt) {
   if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
       this.checked = false;
   }
});
```

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vVxM2/533/)

Comment: Umm. How your answer is better or different then mine?

Comment: And how does it makes it more efficient?

Comment: Your are not wrong, you are perfectly correct, i am just trying to understand how does it makes this code more efficient? or does it hold equal efficiency?

Comment: JQMIGRATE: Logging is active
jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js:41 JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.attr('selected') may use property instead of attribute
jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js:43 console.trace()migrateWarn @ jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js:43
jquery.side-slider.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
http://localhost/connectwater.com/images/slide.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost/connectwater.com/images/menu_sep.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: If you add a div in your foreach sibling doesn't find the other checkboxes. This doesn't work for 'cousins'

Comment: can you lake a fiddle, i can see and tel you the changes.